# Camera is in different position when build .exe(UNITY)

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I'm using a google cardboard camera (GVRMAIN) and it is placed in the center of my gameobject when i build it it goes up. It is now in different position from the game view in unity. Help me guys please

Comment: **Half information is no information** please specify your question provide some code to backup your claim provide some trails and errors of what you have done to solve it and then ask for help..

Answer (score 3):

Maybe your scene gets scaled up or down on the device and the gameobject moves its position from to original position in the unity editor. So if the camera is attached to the center of this gameobject it also changes positions.
You should attach the camera to a gameobject thats always staying on the same position regardless of the current aspect ratio.